# Get Dynamic Link from playstore don`t works

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I`m trying get dynamicLink from download in play store, but just work when app already installed.

This code belo is on the Launcher activity.

The dynamic link was created on server.

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(appLinkData)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                            String inviteCode = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink().getQueryParameter("inviteCode");
                            String user = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink().getQueryParameter("userName");


                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();


                        }
                    });
```

When i try get dynamic link from play i got this log bellow,

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=mypackager cmp=mypackage/path-to-my-activity-launcher }
```

But when i try to get from app already installed i got this log bellow,

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] dat=https://mydomain/... flg=0x14400000 pkg=mypackage cmp=mypackage/myactivity-launcher (has extras) }
```

DynamicLink Version is

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.5'
```

Comment: Can you confirm how you're triggering the link when the app is already installed? If a link redirects to the play store you should get a "continue" button, which will open the app after it is installed. If you just go to the play store when the app is already installed though, theres no place for the link to trigger.